# Is there a way to do a merge using pandas where one column is a list and another column might contain an element in that list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Right now I have a two pandas dataframes:

The first one looks like this:

```
id1 features
0   ['a', 'b']
1   ['c', 'd', 'e']
2   ['f']
```

and the second looks like this:

```
id2 features other
224   'a'      3
264   'z'      3
277   'f'      3
```

and I want to use the pandas `.merge()` function to combine both of the two. The output should look something like this:

```
id1 features other
0    'a'       3 
2    'f'       3
```

I know there might be a way to do it by expanding the first dataframe into multiple rows per value then doing the join, but I am wondering if there is any way to do it without doing this, or what the cleanest way of doing this would be.

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually described the most efficient way to do this: `expanding the first dataframe into multiple rows per value then doing the join`.

The other option I could see is iterating through the second one. Say

```
df1 =\
id features
0   ['a', 'b']
1   ['c', 'd', 'e']
2   ['f']

df2 =\
id features other
0   'a'      3
1   'z'      3
2   'f'      3
```

Do something like:

```py
features_in_df1 = set(np.flatten(df1.feature.values))

output = []
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['feature'] in features_in_df1:
        output.append(row)

df_merge = pd.concat(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df1.merge(df2,on='id')
df2[[y in x for x , y in zip(s.features_x,s.features_y)]]
   id features  other
0   0        a      3
2   2        f      3
```

---

Update

```
df2[df2.features.isin(df1.features.sum())]
   id features  other
0   0        a      3
2   2        f      3
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the clarification that their ids cannot be shared.  I will update the question, my mistake!